# Do Java Property Changes Stay Beyond Program-run?

Tags: java

I'm currently trying to see how the threadcount affects matrix multiplication and have an implementation that is using javas `Stream.parallel().forEach()`, since it always starts with `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() - 1` threads, I'm inclined to use

```
System.setProperty("java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism", threadCount);
```

to change the amount of threads it uses. If I set the Property to something other than default, will that Property stay changed beyond the run of the program?

Comment: No it does not. If you want it to be reused again you need to save it somewhere maybe properties file on program exit and then use that again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Per the [properties tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html):

> The `setProperties` method changes the set of system properties for the current running application. These changes are not persistent.

`setProperty` is just the singular version of `setProperties`, both update the *running* configuration, which isn't persisted.